# return list indices if two conditions met in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the indices in a list if two conditions are met, and store those indices in a new list. At the moment I can find the entries on the list that meet the condition, but cannot figure out how to get the list indices.

The list is:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

My code so far:

```
m2=[]
for i in range(0,len(gmcounter)):
  if countersum[i]==2 and 2 in gmcounter[i]:
    m2.append(gmcounter[i])
print m2
```

Countersum is a list containing the sums of the list elements, so this returns `[[0, 2], [2, 0]]`

And I would like m2 to take the index values where the two conditions are met, so I would like it to m1 to take `[4,5]`

I have an idea it will be something to do with the enumerate function but my attempts to include that so far have not worked

Would greatly appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `i` is already the index where the two conditions are met.

Using `enumerate()`, possibly combined with `zip()` would be the more pythonic method:

```
m2=[]
for i, (csum, counter) in enumerate(zip(countersum, gmcounter)):
    if csum == 2 and 2 in counter:
        m2.append(i)
```

or, using a list comprehension:

```
m2 = [i for i, (csum, counter) in enumerate(zip(countersum, gmcounter)) if csum == 2 and 2 in counter]
```

Comment: @wim: This is what a list comprehension is *for*. It's faster than the loop, because the list has to be built only once, for example.

Comment: Thanks very much, my trouble was in getting the list comprehension to accept two conditions rather than a single one.

Comment: It's OK, I just think readability suffers in this example because the line is so long.  Faster or not is irrelevant for most real-world use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using indexes at all, as @Martijn does. Or you can take your index-based method and simply build a list of the indexes you want:

```
[ i for i in range(len(gmcounter)) if countersum[i]==2 and 2 in gmcounter[i] ]
```

This is less "pythonic" and probably a touch slower, so do get your head around the index-less ways of doing things.